# Sprite Kit: Remove debugging label at bottom corner

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have developed an iOS app using Sprite Kit.  Anyone that has developed an iOS game with Sprite Kit knows of the label at the bottom corner with debugging information.  I am trying to remove the debugging information on the bottom corner which gives the number of nodes and fps.
(ex. 1 node 60.0 fps)

I tried the following code in the `-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size` method in my `.m` file but it doesn't seem to do anything. Is this the correct code for removing the debugging label or is there a better way to remove the label?

```
SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
spriteView.showsNodeCount = NO;
spriteView.showsFPS = NO;
```

Comment: Have you tried " spriteView.showsDrawCount=NO"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size` is not the method where you do this. I guess you are doing this in subclass of `SKScene`. You should do it in `ViewContoller`. Go to the `ViewController` there in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. Just find that somewhere in your code you did this:

```
skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
```

Just comment these two lines or do this:

```
skView.showsFPS = NO;
skView.showsNodeCount = NO;
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: This SHOULD work. I am also developing a game from the SpriteKit template, and this is how I hid the debug labels. It worked in my case. Perhaps the original poster is setting them back to `YES` somewhere else...

Comment: @nicolasmiari > I guess so.

Comment: @poojaM.bohora > No, he is doing this in subclass of SKScene. No in viewController.

Comment: @Rashad: Yes, putting the code in ViewController was the trick.  I was trying to use it in a subclass of SKScene just as you pointed out.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, you go to GameScene.swift, 
look at "skView.showsFPS" and "skView.showsNodeCount" 
repair from "true" to "false". 
Nodes and FPS will be removed at bottom of the screen! good luck

Answer (score 1):

Set `spriteView.showsDrawCount=NO` and check once. I think you have not set it to NO.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `DEBUG` compiler directive, so this debugging label info is visible during development, but doesn't get included in the App Store release build.

```
// GameViewController.swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = self.sceneManager.scene
    scene.gameDelegate = self

    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

#if DEBUG
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
#endif

    skView.presentScene((scene as! SKScene))
}
```